# Backing up Windows 10 system settings and and restoring to a later point in time

Tags: windows-10, backup

I want to install some software on my Windows 10 machine. I would like to backup the system settings and then after installing and testing the software I want to restore the Windows settings as they were prior to installing the software. It's been a while since I did that in an older version of Windows and am not sure how it's done under Windows 10. One other thing I would like, if possible, is that after restoring the system, would it be possible to switch back to the settings as they were after I installed the software? It would be nice to switch between an older and newer backup of the settings. From my understanding when I did this long ago, when you restored an older version, you lost the newer version.

NOTE: I'm not interested in backing up the entire hard drive. Just the settings.

Comment: So you want to create a system restore point. I'm pointing this out, because asking for a software recommendation on SuperUser is off-topic, but yours is not a software recommendation. System restore points indeed don't allow you to switch between old and new.

Comment: Yes, a restore point. I'm not looking for software recommendations. I'm sure Windows 10 has a built in application for doing this. Just not sure what.

Comment: So you already know the answer: Create a restore point knowing the caveat mentioned in the first comment.

Comment: I managed to figure that out but it isn't clear that after restoring whether I can revert back to a "newer" version.

Comment: You can't and that the caveat already mentioned in the first comment: *System restore points indeed don't allow you to switch between old and new.*

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if your hardware could support it, but this sounds like a good use of Virtual Machines, using snapshots.

You could even convert your current physical machine into a virtual one, take a snapshot, do the upgrade, take another snapshot, and flip between the two when testing.